# How do you specify which python distribution to install a module for with pip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install the yweather module for python 3.5 on my mac using pip install, however as i have both python 3.5 and 2.7 i don't know how to specify which distribution to install the module for - how would you do this?

Comment: How do you have them installed?

Comment: This won't answer the question you asked, but you might consider switching to Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It allows you to maintain entirely separated virtual environments (think users with entirely independent installs of all packages, including python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip will install a module for the default python on your system. If you want to be sure that pip installs for a specific version, use pip2 or pip3 instead of pip.

Also if you aren't already, you should consider using [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

[As seen in the docs](https://yweather.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1/intro.html#installation)

> Download the most recent release from yweather’s PyPi page. Unpack the
>   tarball. **From inside the yweather-0.X directory**

**Python 2**

```
python setup.py install
```

**Python 3**

```
python3 setup.py install
```